# How Can I use the Ah 02h , INT 16h interrupt to check three control keys?

Tags: assembly, x86, dos, bios

I want to write a program which ends by pressing three keys: caps lock, nom lock and left shift. Can I use the AH=02h , INT 16h to check if they have been pressed together or not?
What other interrupts can I use?
Curious :)

Here is my code, but I'm not share about how this interrupt works:

```
TITLE 'PressKeys' ;key program

;-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

;DATA SEGMENT
DASEG SEGMENT PARA PUBLIC 'data'

  CHECK DB 01100010b;The number which is used to check the control keys
                    ;in the INT 16H (caps lock,nom lock,left shoft)

  MESG DB 'FINISH $';Massage to say finish                      

DASEG ENDS

;--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

;CODE SEGMENT
COSEG SEGMENT PARA PUBLIC 'code'

  ASSUME CS:COSEG, DS:DASEG, ES:NOTHING, SS:NOTHING


MAIN:

 MOV AX,DASEG

 MOV DS,AX

 ;Check if the caps and nom and left shift keys has been pressed
KLOOP:
MOV AH,02H

  INT 16H 

  TEST AL,CHECK

  Jnz PRESSED ;If the keys has been pressed finish the programm

  JMP KLOOP

PRESSED:;PRINT MESSAGE

    LEA DX,MESG

    MOV AH,09H

    INT 21H           


 ;GET BACK TO OS
 MOV AX,4C00H
 INT 21H    


COSEG ENDS  

;------------------------------------------------------------------------------

;END OF PROGRAMM

END MAIN
```

Comment: "but I'm not share about how this interrupt works" <- that's a bit rude.

Comment: You can look up any interrupt [here](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/int.htm)

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar: It should probably say "sure".

Answer (score 1):

int 16h/2 checks a byte in the BIOS Data Area - 40h:17h (I had to check RBIL to remember that address). You could check that byte yourself, but the interrupt is probably easier.

The `test` instruction is usually used with just a single bit set in the second operand. If you `test` against multiple bits as you're doing, you'll get NZ if any of the three bits are set. Use `test` three times - one bit at a time, or `and al` with your value and then `cmp` with the exact value to see if all three bits are set.

Edit: More Info: When a key is pressed and again when it's released, an IRQ is generated. This is handled by an Interrupt Service Routine, usually int 9. In most cases the "release" interrupt is ignored. In a few cases, we need to "remember" that a key has been pressed and not released ("shift" being the most obvious). This is done by setting (or clearing) a bit in a couple of bytes in the BDA. (only 1 byte for 80-key keyboards - from the museum)

`int 16h` - the "keyboard interrupt" - actually doesn't go near the keyboard controller (that's handled by `int 9`) but interacts with some bytes in the BDA - the "shift flags" you're interested in, the "keyboard buffer" and a couple of bytes - "head pointer" and "tail pointer" into the buffer (if they're the same, no key is available).

So `int 16h/2` will return whatever is set in the byte at 40h:17h - use `int 16h/12h to get "extended shift flags" - both bytes - if you need 'em. In the example you give - 01011001 was it? (I can't see your comment from "edit mode") - I think there are bits indicating "active" rather than "pressed", so it may not do what you want. Notice that only "certain keys" have their pressed/released state saved.

You're doing okay through the interrupt, but the way you use the `test` instruction will indicate "pressed" if any one of the keys is pressed. I understand that you want to check for "all three". See above.

Ralf Brown's Interrupt List - RBIL - has all this information. If you download the whole mess, rather than consult an online version, there's "ports.lst", "memory.lst" and a bunch of other info. I strogly suggest you get it... if you're going to waste your time with 16-bit code. :)

Comment: So this interrupt works for more than one keys at the same time,too? I mean that for example if Ipress four keys like this: 01011001 , it will understand and set each bit? Or it just recognizes one key?

Comment: Instead of interrupt, can I use IN? How can I use it for this problem?

Comment: Yeah... you could write your own int 9 handler. Not a good beginner project.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd better write this instead:

```
...
OR AL, 10011101B
CMP AL, 11111111B
JC KLOOP
...
```

Your code could jump to PRESSED no matter how many of those three keys are pressed. Pressing at least one of the keys would result in success, which is obviously not your intention.
See how the results are subject to JNZ and therefore result in a jump to PRESSED, which is incorrect:

```
TEST AL, 01100010B
AL = 01000000 -> Result NOT Zero
AL = 00100000 -> Result NOT Zero
AL = 00000010 -> Result NOT Zero
```

The important thing is, the AND, OR and TEST instructions are bit-wise i.e. they AND and OR the two operands bit-by-bit. so the whole result remains greater than zero in above examples.
Your using of TEST, instead of AND, though, helps in preserving the original value in AL, and is a good habit to keep.